# How can i get a file name from Response.Header ? C#

Tags: c#, browser, download, filenames, download-manager

This is a code,  C#.

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest _Response =
    (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.ToString());
_Response.Method = "GET";
_Response.Timeout = 120000;
_Response.Accept =
    "application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
_Response.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
_Response.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
_Response.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
_Response.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

System.Net.HttpWebResponse result = (HttpWebResponse)_Response.GetResponse();

for (int i = 0; i < result.Headers.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(result.Headers.ToString());
}
```

And this is a result,

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 06 Sep 2011 17:38:26 GMT
ETag: 
Location: http://fs31.filehippo.com/6428/59e79d1f80a74ead98bb04517e26b730/Firefox Setup 7.0b3.exe
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: You might want to change the name of the _Response variable to _Request.   It's a HttpWebRequest, not a HttpWebResponse, and calling it _Response is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 3):

The correct approach is to see if a filename is provided by the [Content-Disposition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) field and, failing that, to attempt to infer a filename from the Location field.

Be aware than the location field is simply the URL for the download request, and as such may not include an extension or even a meaningful name.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(result.Headers["Location"]);
```

That way, you'll have the file name at the end of the location header.

Comment: It is very similar to Reed Copsey's answer, but that will give only the file name without the rest of the url.

Answer (score 1):

Given your headers from your request, you should be able to do:

```
 string file = result.Headers["Location"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have got the location of the file you can just extract the header you want (in this case I suppose it is indexed at `4` or at `"Location"`) and then take the last part of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The easy and efficient way to retrieve filename from Content-Disposition field:

```
using System.Net.Mime;

HttpWebResponse resp = {YOUR RESPONSE}
string dispHeader = resp.GetResponseHeader("content-disposition");
ContentDisposition disp = new ContentDisposition(dispHeader);
string filename = disp.FileName;
```

Comment: I tried this, but it fails when value of header is like  `attachment; filename*=utf-8''20200217_152840.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

As the file is on a server you will not be able to retrieve the actual filename. Only what the web application is telling you.

This filename is in "Location".

However since the application is telling you that it is text/html it may be formatting the result before it sends it to you. The correct mime type for an executable is application/octet-stream.

On another note. It appears you are downloading the file in which case there is no need to be provided a path. The path of the file you download, is going to be whatever path you place the contents of the downloaded stream into. 
Therefore you save the file and put it wherever you have access to put it.

When the file is created you have to provide a path, otherwise it is placed in the same directory as the executable that is calling it.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you can always parse the WebResponse.ResponseUri.ToString(). Use string.LastIndexOf("/") to find the beginning of the file name and String.IndexOf to see if there is a "?".

```
public static void ExtractFileNameFromUri(string URI, ref string parsedFileName, string fileNameStartDelimiter = "/", string fileNameEndDelimiter = "?")
{
    const int NOTFOUND = -1;

    try
    {
        int startParse = URI.LastIndexOf(fileNameStartDelimiter) + fileNameStartDelimiter.Length;

        if (startParse == NOTFOUND)
            return;

        int endParse = URI.IndexOf(fileNameEndDelimiter);

        if (endParse == NOTFOUND)
            endParse = URI.Length;

        parsedFileName = URI.Substring(startParse, (endParse - startParse));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return;
    }
}
```